# Select Subscribers By Attribute Through SOAP

Tags: marketing-cloud

The Subscriber Object seems to always return a list of attributes (name and value) when requested through SOAP. However, they cannot be requested as a specific property. In the following example Subscriber Attributes come with the Subscriber Object, they are not requested as a specific property:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_profile_attributes_on_the_subscriber_object/

I can filter subscriber retrieves based on top level properties such as Email, SubscriberID, CreatedDate, and more. However, I am not sure how to build a filter for particular attributes. Is there a way to filter retrieving a list of subscribers (all subscriber objects, not subscribers on a particular list) filtered on a profile attribute value? Such as State is Indiana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly retrieve the subscribers object and use a `simplefilterpart` to select by just attribute.

What you would need to do here, is create a "Filter Definition".  [This is the documentation](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_filterdefinition_object/).

Less than ideal, I'm sure, but it is currently the only way to do this.